# Solving an Augmented Matrix with 2 Unknown Constants

Tags: matrices

Consider the system of linear equations in the variables $x, y, z$ given by
$$ax + y + z = 4$$
$$x + by + z = 3$$
$$x + 2by + z = 4$$

Find the values of the constants a and b for which the system has:

(a) no solutions

(b) exactly one solution

(c) infinitely many solutions

Answer (score 0):

from zhe first equation we get
$$z=4-ax-y$$
plugging this in the second and third equation we obtain
$$x(1-a)+y(b-1)=-1$$ (I)
$$x(1-a)+y(2b-1)=0$$ (II)
with $$x(1-a)=-1-y(b-1)$$ we get in (II)
$$y(2b-1)-y(b-1)=1$$
or $$by=1$$
if $$b=0$$ then we have no Solutions.
if $$b\ne 0$$ we get
$$y=\frac{1}{b}$$
now we can compute $x$:
$$x(1-a)=\frac{1-2b}{b}$$
if $$a=1$$ then we get if $$b=\frac{1}{2}$$ then we get infinity Solutions.
If $$b\neq \frac{1}{2}$$ then we have no Solutions.
If $$a\ne 1$$ then we have $$x=\frac{1-2b}{(1-a)b}$$
$$z=\frac{3 a b-4 b+1}{(a-1) b}$$